# Username password validation in node Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

**Pls.. i am completely new Guy to Node js**

**i try this for my learning purpose**

i have created **server.js** file

```
var http=require('http');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var express=require('express');
var fs=require('fs');
var mysql=require('mysql');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session')
var app=express();
var server=http.createServer(app);
var User=[];
server.listen(8000);
var connection=mysql.createConnection({
    host:'****',
    user:'****',
    password:'****'
});  
connection.connect(function(Error,Res){
    if(!Error)
    {
        connection.query('USE USERS');
        connection.query( "select *from USERS",  function(err, rows){
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }else{
                User.push(rows);
            }
        });
    }
});
app.get('/', function(request,response){
    fs.readFile('login.html', function(Error,Res){
        if(!Error)
        {
            response.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/html'});
            response.write(Res);
        }
    });
});
app.use(session({secret: '<mysecret>',saveUninitialized: true,resave: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done(err, user);
});
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                  failureRedirect: '/login',
                                  failureFlash: true })
);
```

i dont know how to validate username and password using passport in node js but anyhow i tried this above

My **login.html** looks like

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
    <script src="assets/js/Angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <div>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="password"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my sql User Table has data like

```
username:Admin,
password:Admin
```

i run the server.js file using command prompt like `node server.js` after running i goto the browser and type `http://localhost:8000` i got the following screen

[image]

And then i type **username** and **password** is **Admin** , **Admin** when i submit i get `Cannot GET /login` i think it means username password is wrong because i specified `failureRedirect: '/login'`. but i provide correct username and password why i got `Cannot GET /login` instead of `Cannot GET /`. where can i do the mistake??? pls Help

Comment: I tried to click the picture....  I knew it was a picture, I still tried to click it.

Comment: `select *from USERS` missing blankspace: `* from`, the server console should print errors.

Comment: The error, `Cannot GET /login`, points to an improper request. The `/login` route is only defined to respond to `POST` requests (`app.post('/login', ...)`), but a `GET` request is being sent to it instead.

Comment: pls friends. atleast provide simple example for username password validation in node js with help of my sql database

Comment: @Xero *I love those rare off-topic comments that make me lol, dude I clicked like 10 times..* Arunkumar, I'd do it the same as in any other language: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1` then `if (result.username == username && result.password == crypt.XXX(password)) { // success } else { // no success }`

Comment: @DanFromGermany Few days ago i posted question like this. many of them suggest to use library( like passport). so i tried this today. but here after i not able to proceed further. so i expect some spark from SO members.

Comment: @Arunkumar I know this sounds a little annoying right now, but the best you can do is going carefully through [the passport guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/). When I first worked with node.js I was confused by some events and triggers, too. Reading and understanding helps significantly.

Answer (score 0):

What is this, **`validPassword()`** method? Do you have it defined?

My bet is that you do not.

So, try to add more logging to the Passport middleware and track the console. Something like bellow, I suspect you'll get no error log at all, because the app will fail before validPassword():

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('MySQL Error: ', err);
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log('Incorrect username error.');
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            console.lg('Trying user.validPassword() call');
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                console.log('Incorrect password.');
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            console.log('All correct, user found: ', user);
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));
```

Comment: yes validPassword() i am not defined. if i put console inside the function its not called??? why above function not executed???

Comment: Because if you want to use validPassword() method, you need to define it first. How is your password stored in db? Plain text or encrypted?

What you need is to essentially define a function `validPassword(password)` which will take the argument and check against that db field. Ie. if plain text, compare the password and stored text, if you hashed it, then hash your input and compare, or use some crypto method you used to store passwords in the first place.